# node module error when creating outlook web add-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-js, fluent

When I created react outlook add-in and start outlook add-in I got this error in webpack

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@fluentui/react-icons/lib/utils/fonts/FluentSystemIcons-Resizable.woff2 1:4
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)
> @ ./node_modules/@fluentui/react-icons/lib/utils/fonts/createFluentFontIcon.js 12:0-67 36:30-46
> @ ./node_modules/@fluentui/react-icons/lib/index.js 25:0-74 25:0-74

webpack 5.90.3 compiled with 9 errors in 20766 ms

Comment: You can read it on the linked page: "Out of the box, webpack only understands JavaScript and JSON files. ". Here you are trying to process a font, which webpack doesn't understand. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51277381/5470544

Comment: In Webpack 5, you should use the [assets module](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) for handling fonts.

Comment: I've given an answer below, but it would help me update Microsoft's documentation if you could provide some more details: Did you create a JavaScript or TypeScript project? What version of Node.js and npm are you using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the basic Office add-in that uses Fluent React UI v9. The workaround is to open the webpack.config.js file in the root of the project and find the line:

```
test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
```

change it to read:

```
test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
```

Comment: Using this test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, I got these two errors. How can I solve it.

ERROR in unable to locate 'S:/Office Work/Dummy Project/New folder/my-app/assets/*' glob

ERROR in unable to locate 'S:/Office Work/Dummy Project/New folder/my-app/manifest*.xml' glob

Comment: When and where do you see this error?

Comment: Now if I make a new add-in project using yo-office and when I start the project I face this error.

Comment: I can't reproduce those errors. Are the files it's looking for really missing? Please answer the questions that I asked above:  Did you create a JavaScript or TypeScript project? What version of Node.js and npm are you using?

Comment: Yes I'm using JavaScript & node version is 20.11.1